# CountIFS with multiple ranges and multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I want to count all the instances that "a" occurs in column a AND "b" occurs in both column b and c. This would be in a match up style. Essentially I am trying to count a head to head where a occurs in column a every time b occurs in the remaining columns

The formula I used is =COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"=a",B1:C4,"=b"). This returns a "#VALUE" error.

I am aware that I could use multiple COUNTIFS but for the real workbook "b" would be spread across 20 columns so this would result in a very long and slow formula. [image]

Comment: So in this instance your desired result is zero?

Comment: You may need `MMULT()`. What is your excel version?

Comment: Maybe something like `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4&B1:B4&C1:C4="abb"))`?

Answer (score 3):

One option:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=SUM(--(BYROW(A1:C4,LAMBDA(a,CONCAT(UNIQUE(a,1))))="ab"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is **another** option,

[image: Formula_Solution]

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--($A$1:$B$4="a")*($B$1:$C$4="b"),{1;1}))
```